# Laravel group by, count and access and eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel

I'd like to group by a foreign key ID, count that group and then in the view be able to access the relationship of that foreign key ID. The first two things (group by and count) succeed with the following query:

```
$collection = Example::selectRaw('count(*) AS total, foreign_key')
->groupBy('foreign_key')
->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
->get();
```

But I can't figure out how I can access the eloquent relationship of the foreign key, so that in the view I can do something like

```
foreach($collection as $c)
{
  $c->total;
  $c->foreign->title
  $c->foreign->address
}
```

Note that the Example Model has the relationship defined:

```
class Example extends Model
{
  public function foreign()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Foreign', 'id', 'foreign_key')
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you dd(); the $c->foreign variable?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump($c) to see what you have in here ?

Comment: As you said that `Foreign` table and `Example` table both are having one to one relationships then why you're doing `groupby` from Example? ? I don't think that you'll get more than one in the count.

Comment: There was a spelling mistake in `$c->foreign`... Sorry and thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what you're expecting in outout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your COntroller**

```
$collection = Example::selectRaw('count(*) AS total, foreign_key')->get();
```

**In your blade**

```
foreach($collection as $c)
{
  $c->total;
  $c->foreign->title
  $c->foreign->address
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$collection = Example::selectRaw('count(*) AS total, foreign_key')
->with('foreign')
->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Also, you probably don't need `groupBy()` since it is a one to one relationship and thus would return only one result (as @DilipHirapara suggested).

Comment: The `groupBy` groups all the foreigns with the same ID and then counts these groups, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: @eskimo Don't you then need a `hasMany()` relationship rather than `hasOne()`?